# xml element comparison

Tags: xml, compare

Wow to compare the elements from two different xml files in C#? Only element name has to be compared not the element value.

I am using:

```
XDocument file1 = XDocument.Load(dest_filename);
XDocument file2 = XDocument.Load(source_filename);

if (file1.Nodes().Intersect(file2.Nodes()).Count() > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("hey i popped up");
}
```

but it is comparing the value too, which i don't want to compare..

Answer (score 0):

Given file1.xml:

```
<root>
  <a></a>
  <b></b>
  <c></c>
</root>
```

and file2.xml:

```
<root>
  <a></a>
  <b></b>
  <b></b>
  <c></c>
  <d></d>
</root>
```

The following code will result in four message boxes (for nodes a, b, b and c)

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("file1.xml"));
XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("file2.xml"));

var matches = from a in doc.Element("root").Descendants()
            join b in doc2.Element("root").Descendants() on a.Name equals b.Name
            select new { First = a, Second = b };

foreach (var n in matches)
    MessageBox.Show(n.First.ToString() + " matches " + n.Second.ToString());
```

Hope that helps :)